# Tooltip in the report is getting under other region in Oracle APEX IR

Tags: css, tooltip, css-position, oracle-apex, z-index

I am trying to create a tooltip in Oracle APEX Interactive Report. Please find the sample application details below.
When i hover on the tooltip with an hourglass icon. It is getting under another layer. Could you please help me.

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=70837:1

```
    .tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  top: -5px;
  right: 105%;
}
```

Comment: There are lots of problems here. Rather than reinvent the wheel, checkout the plug-ins on apex.world: https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:700:::NO:700::&cs=3_hg4TXo_4rbcqKWZvbUW5k_jEJSS-I0WWpihpmifrPHcwj2q0pD1HIIMUlutx6Fd8OFO3jJgQuffMgQBwSIFlg

Comment: This one looks the most likely to fit your use case: https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:9073237614275::NO:710:P710_PLG_ID:DE.DANIELH.APEXTOOLTIP Another option is to use jQuery tooltips: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/